# Abnormal issue with Zend_Form_Element_Captcha...?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, captcha, zend-form-element

In my Zend Application, I am facing an abnormal problem with the Captcha element. When I try to view the form in which I had used this Captcha element on my local machine it is working fine, but when I upload it to my Debian Server It is not working properly...!!!

Difference is as follows:
[image]

As you can see on localhost the text inside the captcha is shown to the user, Where as on the Server[Debian], the text is missing!!!!!

I had used followig code to create the Captcha Element on my Zend Form:

```
    $elements = array();
    $captchaElement = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha',
                                                array('label'   => "Ihr generierter Textcode:",
                                                      'captcha' => array('captcha' => 'Image',
                                                      'name'    => 'myCaptcha',
                                                      'wordLen' => 5,
                                                      'timeout' => 300,
                                                      'font'    => 'verdana.ttf',
                                                      'imgDir'  => 'captcha/',
                                                      'imgUrl'  => '/captcha/')
                                                     )
                                                 );
    $elements[] = $captchaElement;
    foreach ($elements as $index => $element)
    {
        $element->setAttrib('tabindex', ($index + 1));
    }
```

Can anyone tell me What mistake I am doing...?

Thanks In Advance.....

Comment: Do you have the font on the production server?

Comment: @bububaba : Yes I do have verdana.ttf font in the server, but I'm not sure it is supported by Debian.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/7001725/1145086, this is common with some versions of php on linux. Should be fixed in current version but your host may not have upgraded yet.

Comment: check is font file has read permission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change this font to any other to check if Debian support it
2. Set absolutely path for font and images:

   ```
   $captchaOptions = array(
       'label' => "Enter key",
       'captcha' => array(
           'captcha'   => 'Image',
           'wordLen'   => 4,
           'width'     => 197,
           'timeout'   => 120,
           'expiration'=> 300,
           'font'      => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/ttf/arial.ttf',
           'imgDir'    => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/images/captcha',
           'imgUrl'    => '/images/captcha/',
           'gcFreq'    => 5
       ),
   );
   ```
3. What ZF version do you use? Cause after 1.7 there a bug in decorator, you have to set own decorator otherwise Zend_Captcha doesn't work:

   ```
   $captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('Captcha', $captchaOptions);
   $captchaDecor = array_merge(array(new Decorator_Captcha()), $captcha->getDecorators());
   $captcha->setDecorators($captchaDecor);
   ```

**Decorator_Captcha file below**

```
class Decorator_Captcha extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Render captcha
     *
     * @param  string $content
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();
        if (!method_exists($element, 'getCaptcha')) {
            return $content;
        }

        $view    = $element->getView();
        if (null === $view) {
            return $content;
        }

        $placement = $this->getPlacement();
        $separator = $this->getSeparator();

        $captcha = $element->getCaptcha();
        $markup  = $captcha->render($view, $element);
        switch ($placement) {
            case 'PREPEND':
                $content = $content . $separator . $markup;
                break;
            case 'APPEND':
            default:
                $content = $markup . $separator .  $content;
        }

        return $content;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As RockyFord already in the comments wrote, it isnt a ZF bug but a PHP bug.

You will find solutions in the already provided answeres of: [Zend captcha Image generates blank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7001725/315257)